# Firebase Cloud Functions problem with using @type/googlemaps namespace: "ReferenceError: google is not defined"

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-functions

I need to use the Google Maps Api libraries in my Cloud Functions.
I installed the namespace with `npm install --save @types/google-maps` and so vsCode doesn't give me any compile error, but when the cloud function triggers  i got this error:

```
ReferenceError: google is not defined at exports.onZoneCreate.functions.database.ref.onCreate(/user_code/lib/index.js:93:20)
```

The triggered function is

```
 export const onZoneCreate = functions.database
.ref('/Zones/Areas/{CAP}/{IDzona}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {


    const cap: string = context.params.CAP
    const IDZona: string = context.params.IDzona
    console.log('new zone (id Zona:' + IDZona + ') from CAP ' + cap)

    const feature = snapshot.val();
    const vettoreCoordinatePoligono = feature.geometry.coordinates

    console.log(vettoreCoordinatePoligono);

    var ref = snapshot.ref
    var root = ref.root
    var poly = new google.maps.Polyline(vettoreCoordinatePoligono)

    var risultato = getSquareDivision(poly);

    console.log(risultato)

    return root.child('prova/' + cap + IDZona).set(risultato);


})
```

where the functions that i use inside this one are:

## 1

```
function getSquareDivision(polygon: google.maps.Polyline) {

var bound = getBoundsRectangle(polygon);

var lowx,
    highx,
    lowy,
    highy,
    lats = [],
    lngs = [],
    vertices = polygon.getPath(),
    verticeslength: number = vertices.getLength()


for (var i = 0; i < verticeslength; i++) {
    lngs.push(vertices.getAt(i).lng());
    lats.push(vertices.getAt(i).lat());
}

lats.sort();
lngs.sort();

//VALORI VARIABILI
lowx = lats[0];
highx = lowx + 0.01;
lowy = lngs[0];
highy = lowy + 0.01;

var startHighX = highx;
var startLowX = lowx;

var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(lowx, lowy);
var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(highx, highy);
var llb = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);

var x = 0;
var y = 0;

var elements = [];

while (bound.contains(llb.getCenter())) {
    var i = 0;
    while (bound.contains(llb.getCenter())) {

        sw = new google.maps.LatLng(lowx, lowy);
        ne = new google.maps.LatLng(highx, highy);
        llb = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
        var name = x + "" + y;

        elements[i] = [{ name: name, geometry: llb.toJSON() }];

        highx = highx + 0.01;
        lowx = lowx + 0.01;
        i++;
        x++;

    }

    highx = startHighX;
    lowx = startLowX;
    highy = highy + 0.01;
    lowy = lowy + 0.01;
    sw = new google.maps.LatLng(lowx, lowy);
    ne = new google.maps.LatLng(highx, highy);
    llb = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
    y++;
    x = 0;
}

return elements;

}
```

## 2

```
function polygonCenter(poly) {


var lowx,
    highx,
    lowy,
    highy,
    lats = [],
    lngs = [],
    vertices = poly.getPath();

for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    lngs.push(vertices.getAt(i).lng());
    lats.push(vertices.getAt(i).lat());
}

lats.sort();
lngs.sort();
lowx = lats[0];
highx = lats[vertices.length - 1];
lowy = lngs[0];
highy = lngs[vertices.length - 1];
var center_x = lowx + ((highx - lowx) / 2);
var center_y = lowy + ((highy - lowy) / 2);
return (new google.maps.LatLng(center_x, center_y));
}
```

## 3

```
function getBoundsRectangle(poly) {



var lowx,
    highx,
    lowy,
    highy,
    lats = [],
    lngs = [],
    vertices = poly.getPath();

for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    lngs.push(vertices.getAt(i).lng());
    lats.push(vertices.getAt(i).lat());
}

lats.sort();
lngs.sort();
lowx = lats[0];
highx = lats[vertices.length - 1];
lowy = lngs[0];
highy = lngs[vertices.length - 1];

var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(lowx, lowy);
var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(highx, highy);
var llb = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);

return llb;
}
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
  "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
  "build": "tsc",
  "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
  "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
  "start": "npm run shell",
  "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
  "logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
  "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
  "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
  "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
  "request":"2.88.0"
},
  "devDependencies": {
  "tslint": "~5.8.0",
  "typescript": "~2.8.3"
},
  "private": true
}
```

this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
   "lib": ["es6"],
   "module": "commonjs",
   "noImplicitReturns": true,
   "outDir": "lib",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "target": "es6"
   },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
   "src"
   ],
  "files":[
  "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts"
   ],
  "exclude": [
  "node_modules"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using another library:  http://turfjs.org/

This library contains all the implementation similar to google-maps-api ones.

I hade to change a lot of code but it works right now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have loaded type declarations for the Google Maps API but haven't loaded the actual API implementation.  In any case, the regular Google Maps API is only designed to run in browsers.  A quick [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=using+google+maps+API+from+a+google+cloud+function) found me [this page](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/devops/mapscloudfunctions) that indicates that in Google Cloud Functions, you want the [`@google/maps` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps) instead, which has [its own type declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google__maps).